# Regex: Ignore a part of the string

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression that ignores a part of a string

example:

Blinds $100/$200 - Tournament 2020202220

Blinds $100/$200 Antes 20 - Tournament 2020202220

im using this expresion:

```
Blinds\s[$€](100)/[$€\d]+\s(Ante\s[$€\d]+\s)?.*
```

but it match for both strings...

What i need is an expression that match the first case and ignore the second
and a second expression that matchs the second but ignores the first.

im not very familiar with regex expressions ... thanks in advance

Comment: You should mention which technology you are using VB, .net, java or any other.

Comment: i´m using a program named placemint http://sourceforge.net/projects/placemint/ it use the expressions to match the tittle in a window and reposition the window afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First Line

This will match the first line

`Blinds\b\s*([$€]\d*/[$€]\d*)\s*[-]\s*\bTournament\b\s*(\d*)`

[image]

Captured groups:

group 0: "Blinds $100/$200 - Tournament 2020202220"

1. "$100/$200"
2. "2020202220"

## Second Line

`Blinds\b\s*([$€]\d*/[$€]\d*\s*Antes\s*\d*\s*)[-]\s*Tournament\s*(\d*)`

[image]

Captured groups:

group 0 "Blinds $100/$200 Antes 20 - Tournament 2020202220"

1. "$100/$200 Antes 20 "
2. "2020202220"

Comment: what did you use to generate the regex images? snazzy.

Comment: I'm using debuggex.com . Although it doesn't support lookbehinds. It's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.