# Regex ignoring part of the string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to Regex. I've looked at this one but can't figure out how to do the below [Regex: Ignore a part of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746253/regex-ignore-a-part-of-the-string).

test string

**function name --oldEvaluate

--oldEvaluate

newEvaluate**


The result should be function name newEvaluate.
Thanks

Current code: function name\s*([-]\s*.*\n)*(\w*)

Comment: And the code? Where is the code of your program?

Comment: function name\s*([-]\s*.*\n)*(\w*)

Comment: Current code: function name\s*([-]\s*.*\n)*(\w*)

Answer (score 0):

You should create group for "function name".

```
(function name)\s*([-]\s*.*\n)*(\w*)
```

and then if I understand your regex correctly return "group[1] group[3]"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying this in C#

Look at this page for an example using the regular expression replace function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Something like:

```
mynewstring = Regex.Replace(input_string, @"sub-string Pattern to match", replacementString)
```

should work for you.