# New regexp with two same names so ignore a part of it

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to create a test in jquery to test if a name is present in a string that comes from JSON.
If that test pass then some html is added to a div.

The problem I'm facing now is that my JSON have two values with almost identical names. In my current code the test skips to the second value (because it's the same name) and displays the wrong value.

To clarify (**I stripped a whole lot of code for readabillity**):

JSON

```
{
"product": {
    "specs": {
        "268493": {
            "id": 268493,
            "title": "Hoogte (mm)",
            "value": "120"
        },
        "268502": {
            "id": 268502,
            "title": "Hoogte stapel (mm)",
            "value": "2200"
        },
```

My code:

```
$.getJSON(url+'?format=json', function(data){
  var uspHtml = [];

  var height = 0,
      reHeight = new RegExp( getAjaxTranslation('hoogte') , "i" );

  $.each(data.product.specs, function (specId, spec) {
   /* get product measurements */

   // a whole lot more tests //
    ......
    else if (reHeight.test(spec.title) )
      height = spec.value;
  });

  var html = height;

 /* show product usps */
 if(data.product.data_03){
    var productUsps = data.product.data_03;
    var usp = productUsps.split(',');
    usp.forEach(function(item) {
      uspHtml.push('<li><i class="bullit"></i> '+item+'</li>');
    });  
    uspHtml = uspHtml.join('');
 }
  container.find('.product-usp ul').html(uspHtml);
  container.find('.product-bottom .measurements span').html(html);
```

As you can see there's `Hoogte (mm)` and `Hoogte stapel (mm)`. When I use the test:

```
else if (reHeight.test(spec.title) )
      height = spec.value;
```

both will pass! What I actually want is to ignore `Hoogte stapel (mm)`.

So my question is, is there a way to ignore some part of the string or value?
For example make a regExp with 'hoogte' but ignore 'stapel' or something.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746253/regex-ignore-a-part-of-the-string) but I have no clue how that will apply to my question.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regular expression to use a negative lookahead:

```
var reHeight = new RegExp('^.*hoogte(?!.*stapel).*$', 'i');
console.log(reHeight.test('Hoogte (mm)')); // true
console.log(reHeight.test('Hoogte stapel (mm)')); // false
```

Comment: Excellent... Works perfectly!